# How do I filter and show checkboxes when an option is selected under select tag?

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox, frontend

I want to filter checkboxes on selecting an option in select(something like filtering dependent checkboxes)

```
<select> 
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">D</option>
   <option value="D">C</option>
<select>

<label for="1">1</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" for="1">
<label for="2">2</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" for="2">
<label for="3">3</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" for="3">
<label for="4">4</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" for="4">
<label for="5">5<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" for="5">
```

Now say if the option with value A is selected then i want to show the checkboxes 3,4,5

How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can make use of the `onChange` event of the drop-down box.

Answer (score 0):

For jquery, you can make use of `.change()` event handler to do so.

I give an example for your reference.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#dropDown").change(function(){
      switch(this.value){
        case "A":
          $("#1").show();
          break;
      }
    });
});
```

```css
span{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown"> 
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">D</option>
   <option value="D">C</option>
<select>

<span id="1">
  <label for="1">1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" for="1">
</span>
<label for="2">2</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" for="2">
<label for="3">3</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" for="3">
<label for="4">4</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" for="4">
<label for="5">5<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" for="5">
```